# Usage of пока-пока

Tags: словоупотребление

I know the russian word 'пока' has a number of meanings, the most prevalent one being the informal 'bye'.
In some contexts, however, I have come across 'пока-пока', but couldn't find much info about the use of this.

Is it just a "cutesy" way of saying bye?
In which situations would this be used (over пока)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's a babyish way to say bye, similar to English "bye-bye".

It can be used whenever English "bye-bye" would be used, and I believe is a Russian calque of the English word.

Comment: "Therefrom" probably died as a word a couple hundred years ago, by the way—well unless you're a lawyer))

Comment: @VCH250: it sounds so cool!

Comment: @ Quassnoi it is cool, to be honest; but at the same time it's very very formal. I read lots of Science papers (from journals) and I've never seen it. It could be used, and it could become popular again, but for now I'd avoid it))

Comment: @VCH250 i too insist on using it and other [pronominal adverbs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_pronominal_adverbs), if German has them why not English? and they remind me of Russian and Hebrew because they are built almost synthetically... they're underappreciated

Comment: In writing it would be fine, I think. In speech you would have to work it in seamlessly. A listener would probably think they heard something like "from there" which is the same idea in any case.

Comment: The most calquish Russian calque i heard was "гуд-баюшки" :)

Answer (score 4):

It is common and familiar but not babyish. 
Our Russian friends and family relatives use it all the time